# SQL Server - 2008 : Nested Select, need improve execution faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

Here the problem:

- **First** I have a nested query, for which I need to improve the execution time and make it faster. Imagine 47 seconds at first time and second time was 46 / 45 second. Second was running by cache (the second execution always faster than first time but not this).
- **Second** that query uses `SUM`, `CAST`, `CASE` in each sub select. Can't dodge that
- **Third** I read some another solution from internet using OPTION (FAST 500).

Here the example :

```
SELECT [cutomerSection],
       SUM(DEBIT) AS DEBIT,
       SUM(CREDIT) AS CREDIT,
       SUM([OTHERS]) AS 'OTHERS'
FROM
    (-- SECTOR A
     SELECT cb.paymentGrp AS 'cutomerSection',
         CASE
           WHEN j.paymentStat = 'DEBIT' THEN SUM(CAST(ISNULL(isnull(qty, 1)*(100-disc)*d.adm/100, 0) AS INT)) + SUM(CAST(ISNULL(isnull(qty, 1)*(100-disc)*(d.fee-d.adm)/100, 0) AS INT))
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'DEBIT',
       CASE
           WHEN j.paymentStat = 'CREDIT' THEN SUM(CAST(ISNULL(isnull(qty, 1)*(100-disc)*d.adm/100, 0) AS INT)) + SUM(CAST(ISNULL(isnull(qty, 1)*(100-disc)*(d.fee-d.adm)/100, 0) AS INT))
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'CREDIT',
       CASE
           WHEN (j.paymentStat = ''
                 OR j.paymentStat IS NULL) THEN SUM(CAST(ISNULL(isnull(qty, 1)*(100-disc)*d.adm/100, 0) AS INT)) + SUM(CAST(ISNULL(isnull(qty, 1)*(100-disc)*(d.fee-d.adm)/100, 0) AS INT))
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'OTHERS'
   FROM tbactDetail d WITH(NOLOCK)
   LEFT JOIN tbsectorSection j WITH(NOLOCK) ON d.tranCode = j.tranCode
   LEFT JOIN tbact t ON (d.actCode=t.actCode
                         AND t.sectorCode = j.sectorCode)
   LEFT JOIN tbCustomer c WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.custCode=j.custCode
   LEFT JOIN tbfrontDesk a WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.struckNo=j.struk
   LEFT JOIN tbpaymentList cb WITH(NOLOCK) ON cb.paymentK = a.paymentK
   LEFT JOIN tbleading dc ON dc.leadCode = j.leadCode
   LEFT JOIN tbsector p ON j.sectorCode = p.sectorCode
   WHERE (j.deleted IS NULL
          OR j.deleted = 0)
     AND a.status = 'FINISH'
     AND (j.tranDate BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-01 23:59:59')
   GROUP BY cb.paymentGrp,
            j.paymentStat
   UNION ALL -- SECTOR PARK
SELECT cb.paymentGrp AS 'cutomerSection',
       CASE
           WHEN t.paymentStat = 'DEBIT' THEN SUM(CAST(isnull(d.rate*d.qty*(100-disc)/100, 0) AS INT))
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'DEBIT',
       CASE
           WHEN t.paymentStat = 'CREDIT' THEN SUM(CAST(isnull(d.rate*d.qty*(100-disc)/100, 0) AS INT))
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'CREDIT',
       CASE
           WHEN (t.paymentStat = ''
                 OR t.paymentStat IS NULL) THEN SUM(CAST(isnull(d.rate*d.qty*(100-disc)/100, 0) AS INT))
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'OTHERS'
   FROM tbparkDetail d
   LEFT JOIN tbTranPark t ON d.tranCode = t.tranCode
   JOIN tbsectorSection j ON t.strukPoli = j.struk
   LEFT JOIN tbCustomer c WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.custCode=j.custCode
   LEFT JOIN tbfrontDesk a WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.struckNo=j.struk
   JOIN tbpaymentList cb ON a.paymentK = cb.paymentK
   LEFT JOIN tbleading dc ON dc.leadCode=j.leadCode
   LEFT JOIN tbsector p ON j.sectorCode=p.sectorCode
   WHERE (j.deleted IS NULL
          OR j.deleted=0)
     AND (t.strukPoli IS NOT NULL
          OR t.strukPoli <> ''
          OR t.strukPoli <> '--')
     AND a.status = 'FINISH'
     AND (j.tranDate BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-01 23:59:59')
   GROUP BY cb.paymentGrp,
            t.paymentStat
   UNION ALL -- SECTOR FRONT
SELECT cb.paymentGrp AS 'cutomerSection',
       CASE
           WHEN t.paymentStat = 'DEBIT' THEN SUM(CAST(isnull(d.rate*(100-disc)/100, 0) AS INT))
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'DEBIT',
       CASE
           WHEN t.paymentStat = 'CREDIT' THEN SUM(CAST(isnull(d.rate*(100-disc)/100, 0) AS INT))
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'CREDIT',
       CASE
           WHEN (t.paymentStat = ''
                 OR t.paymentStat IS NULL) THEN SUM(CAST(isnull(d.rate*(100-disc)/100, 0) AS INT))
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'OTHERS'
   FROM tbDetailRadioterapi d
   LEFT JOIN tbtranFront t ON d.tranCode = t.tranCode
   LEFT JOIN tbsectorSection j ON t.strukPoli = j.struk
   LEFT JOIN tbCustomer c WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.custCode=j.custCode
   LEFT JOIN tbfrontDesk a WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.struckNo = j.struk
   LEFT JOIN tbpaymentList cb ON a.paymentK = cb.paymentK
   LEFT JOIN tbleading dc ON dc.leadCode=j.leadCode
   LEFT JOIN tbsector p ON j.sectorCode=p.sectorCode
   WHERE (t.deleted IS NULL
          OR t.deleted=0)
     AND (strukPoli IS NOT NULL
          OR strukPoli <>''
          OR strukPoli <>'--')
     AND a.status='FINISH'
     AND (j.tranDate BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-01 23:59:59')
   GROUP BY cb.paymentGrp,
            t.paymentStat) AS a
GROUP BY [cutomerSection]
```

Third using option (fast 500), I don't know why but always got error :

> Incorect Syntax near OPTION

PS : Sorry for my bad English

Comment: When problem solving, your first step is to break into pieces and test individual pieces. First test each piece (3) of the `UNION ALL` and work out if any one of them contributes to the time taken. Also use CTRL-L and see if it suggests an index

Comment: @TogaNama there are some factors to optimize a query. It also depends on your database structure. To improve and optimize the query you need to manage or create indexes on tables and then try to refactor your query.